# How do I deserialize a list of XML tags while keeping class inheritance intact?

Tags: c#, xml, inheritance, deserialization

I have an XML file that looks a little like this

```xml
<Root>
    <People>
        <Person>
            <Name>John</Name>
        </Person>
        <Customer>
            <Name>Johnny</Name>
            <Money>400</Money>
        </Customer>
        <Student>
            <Name>Johnson</Name>
            <GPA>2.5</GPA>
        </Student>
    </People>
</Root>
```

and some classes that mirror this, using inheritance.

```cs
public class Person
{
    public string Name;
}
public class Customer : Person
{
    public int Money;
}
public class Student : Person
{
    public float GPA;
}
public class Root
{
    public List<Person> People;
}
```

I want to be able to deserialize the XML into a `Root` instance, keeping the values of `Money` and `GPA` intact when the child classes are inserted into the `People` list. I was hoping for a clean solution with `XmlSerializer`, but I will take basically anything at this point.

I have tried messing with `XmlIncludeAttribute`, `XmlChoiceIdentifierAttribute`, and `XmlElementAttribute` to varying degrees, but the data in either of the two inherited classes doesn't populate when casting to the child classes (if I can cast at all).

Note: The XML files I am operating on come from a outside source, so editing the XML structure isn't viable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works with [`XmlArrayItemAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmltypeattribute?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-7.0).

```cs
public class Root
{
    [XmlArrayItem(typeof(Person), ElementName = "Person")]
    [XmlArrayItem(typeof(Customer), ElementName = "Customer")]
    [XmlArrayItem(typeof(Student), ElementName = "Student")]
    public List<Person> People { get; set; } 
}
```

[Demo @ .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/QIrV30)